# Recover JavaScript files from deleted partition

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, javascript

I deleted my whole partition by mistake. To make things worse I created a new partition over it (I didn't leave it like unallocated space). However I didn't copy anything to that partition or used it in any way. I tried some data recovery software tools (only to preview what would they recover). I could restore my video files, pictures, audio, html, etc... However I couldn't find any javascript files. Is it at all possible to recover javascript files. If it is do you have any software to recommend (Windows 10 User). Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Well actually no. I know how to recover my "normal" files. I just have problems recovering my javascript files. Ty for your time nevertheless.

Comment: Files are files. The same methods are used to recover any file given what you did to your disk. Javascript files have no special qualities that make them different.

Comment: I am not a computer expert by any means. So I could have made some mistakes recovering the files. However this recovery process seems pretty straightforward. After the search it would list all the files found by type categories. For example I tried "imyfone anyrecover" and it listed all the files found sorted by type categories. I couldn't find javascript files anywhere. No category for *.js extension. But there was category for html, txt, doc, epub and so on... So what am I missing here? Thanks for you time dude. Appreciated.

Comment: You used the wrong tool for the job. You used a tool that may be friendly for non-technical users, but it does that by assuming you only want to recover "common" file types. You'll need to select a tool that recovers all files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If you happen to know some tool that might help me please let me know. Have a great day.